# How can I round up a number to half in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a program that will round up a float number like: 18.33333
to 18.5.

I tried math.ceil but It wont work like I expected.

```
import math

number1 = 18.3333

print(math.ceil(float(number1)))
```

I want it to be 18.5. But it turns out as 19.

Comment: Multiply by 2, round, divide by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can round x/2, then multiply by 2:

```
def round_to_half(x):
    return round(x*2)/2

for test in [0.12, 0.26, 13.78, 14.27]:
    print(test, round_to_half(test))
```

Output:

```
0.12 0.0
0.26 0.5
13.78 14.0
14.27 14.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just double, round then cut in half. Sort of a work around, but does the job:

```
import math

number1 = 18.3333


round(number1*2)/2
```

Or use a function:

```
def mod_round(x, base=.5):
    return (base * round(float(x)/base))

mod_round(number1. base=.5)
```